# Is it possible to get measure-object to return 0 rather than null/nothing for Sum when the array is empty?

Tags: arrays, powershell, measure

I'm using `measure-object` to produce the count of the number of items in an array for a single property, and also the sum of the values of that property.

The array comes out of an imported CSV that is passed through `where-object` to filter and so it is possible that sometimes the array will be empty.

In the code where I'm building an array of objects with properties for creation of an output CSV, I access the `.count` and `.sum` properties of the `measure-object` cmdlet output for several different input arrays.

If the array measured was empty, the count will still have a value of 0 which I can use (I guess because even an empty array has a count (of 0), but the sum property doesn't exist/has no value. Therefore, the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add a property fails with "attempted to divide by zero".

The lines that fail are working out a percentage to put into the property value (using sums from two arrays) but the divisor is never zero, it's only the dividend that can sometimes be zero so I don't understand why I get the divide by zero error.

Anyone able to explain either how to force `measure-object` to return a sum of zero if there were no items in the array measured, or avoid the divide by zero error?

Sample code below:

```
$report = @()
$obj = New-Object System.Object
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $Table[0].ENDDATE
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Environment -Value "PRODUCTION"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Total_CPU_Seconds -Value ($ProdAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompanyA_CPU_Seconds -Value ($CompAProdStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompanyB_CPU_Seconds -Value ($CompBProdStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "%CompanyA_CPU" -Value ("{0:N2}" -f (($CompAProdStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum/($ProdAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum*100))
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "%CompanyB_CPU" -Value ("{0:N2}" -f (($CompBProdStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum/($ProdAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum*100))
$report += $obj
$obj = New-Object System.Object
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $Table[0].ENDDATE
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Environment -Value "DEVELOPMENT"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Total_CPU_Seconds -Value ($DevAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompanyA_CPU_Seconds -Value ($CompADevStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompanyB_CPU_Seconds -Value ($CompBDevStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "%CompanyA_CPU" -Value ("{0:N2}" -f (($CompADevStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum/($DevAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum*100))
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "%CompanyB_CPU" -Value ("{0:N2}" -f (($CompBDevStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum/($DevAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum*100))
$report += $obj
```

The divide by zero errors happen on the line of code working out the percentage for the DEVELOPMENT environment (which can be empty for CompanyB).

Comment: As to your divide by zero error: Can you verify, that `($DevAllStats | Measure-Object -Property CPUTIME -Sum).Sum` or any other divisor is neither `$null` nor `0`?

Comment: It appears that it is perhaps possible, just trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Your suggestion works a treat - also added in some additional checks of my own :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an explicit type cast to make `Measure-Object` return a sum of zero instead of null, if the array happens to be empty:

```
(@() | Measure-Object -Property Foo -Sum).Sum -as [double]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, `Measure-Object` returns null whenever you use the Property parameter with an input collection that has no items. The `Count` property is special, in that it always exists and will give you 0 when called on null. If the object has its own Count property that will be displayed.

One option is to not use the Property parameter like so:

```
($ProdAllStats.CpuTime | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

I still find it kind of verbose so I'd probably create a function:

```
function Get-Sum {

   param(
       [string]$Property
   )

   if ($property -ne $null) {
       ($input.$property | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
   } else {
       ($input | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
   }
}
```